# Indexing a table for better performance by a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, indexing

What index/indexes would you recommend to be created on the table for making the following type of query more efficient:

```
SELECT MAX(val1)
FROM table
WHERE val2 = 'x' OR val3 = 'y'
```

x and y are of course variable. val2 and val3 are almost always unique, some duplicates may occur.

Comment: umm.. an index on val2, and on val3

Comment: What have you tried? Optimal indexing is often dependent on things like table size, etc. Are you having trouble with this query right now? Do you have any other indexes on the table already?

Comment: You'll also need an index on val1, in order to find the MAX value fast.

Comment: If val2 and/or val3 have low cardinality i.e. only have a few different values, than adding an index will not work because the database will refuse the use the index.

Comment: @Johan, but if there were two indexes: `val2 ASC+val1 DESC` and `val3 ASC+val1 DESC`, they would have a better chance to be used (even with low cardinality of val2/val3) if the query was written like in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have an index on `val2`+`val1` and another on `val3`+`val1`
and write query like:

```
SELECT MAX(val1)
FROM (SELECT max(val1) FROM table where val2 = 'x'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT max(val1) FROM table val3 = 'y'
     ) dt
```

Comment: here's an extra thought, since the OP's going for the `MAX`, make the index: `val2 ASC+val1 DESC` and the other: `val3 ASC+val1 DESC`.  I think having `val1 DESC` as part of the index will be better than just having val1 as an included column on the index.  I'd think that `MAX` would optimize that the index is `DESC`.

Comment: Used your query with the following indexes which resulted in index seeks (your indexes gave index scans).     CREATE INDEX ix_test3 ON dbo.table1(val2)
    CREATE INDEX ix_test4 ON dbo.table1(val3)